# Handling loops and combining values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have a table like this.

```
 author_id   author_state     author_name  
 1           CA             Hello
 2           MI             World
 3           CA             How
 4           MI             Are
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this. In other words, I should loop it and combine the state values first and display the details.

Here is my PHP Code

```
 <table>
<tr><td>Author ID</td><td>Author State</td><td>Author Name</td></tr>
<?php
$row_data = mysql_query("select * from author" );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($row_data) ) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['author_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['author_state']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['author_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

My Expected output is to combine the state and display something like below:

```
Author ID               Author Name
=======================================

CA
==
1                       Hello
3                       How


MI
==
2                      World
4                      Are
```

Comment: Hint: Use `ORDER BY author_state` in your query, then look for its value to change when iterating the loop.

Comment: Also please note that the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky - Noted ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily, by sorting your output by author_state, and using a variable to keep track of which state you're outputting. If the state changes, then you simply output the state as a new header.

You can take advantage of the SQL `order by` clause so that you don't have to sort the data yourself.

Here is an edit of your code, where I've simply added the `order by` to your `mysql_query()`, and added a variable for `$current_state`.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Author ID</td><td>Author State</td><td>Author Name</td></tr>
<?php
$current_state = "";
$row_data = mysql_query("select * from author order by author_state" );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($row_data) ) {

    // Output the "new" state
    if ($row['author_state'] != $current_state)
    {
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">{$row['author_state'}}</td></tr>";
        $current_state = $row['author_state'];
    }
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['author_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['author_state']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['author_name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

As a side note, I would strongly encourage you to look into using mysqli or PDO instead of the mysql_* functions. The mysql_* functions are only availble in very old versions of PHP (they were completely removed in PHP7).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really helpful and works like a charm ! Keep going ! Thanks a ton